# Why deploying and debugging are so slow (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

I have started to develop with react-native and i am struggling on technical issues all the time when deploying or debugging my application. 
I tried running the app in two ways:

1. With expo (`expo start`) 
   With this option expo extract+compile+run my app on my local android simulator which takes 60-70 secodns for every change (via hot-reloading)
2. Running on my iPhone with expo client 
   That takes me also 60-70 seconds and debugging is not convenient.

Is there any way developing faster with react-native? 
**It takes me one hour for creting a simple screen with Form and AsyncStorage + checking the logic (insted of 10 minutes)**

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Could be many factors. Slow computer, hard drive full.... Perhaps clean your build folders.  Very hard to diagnose from what little information you privide.